# configuring apache to server django-logdb static files

Tags: django

I don't know why I'm being so brain-dead about this, but I can't figure it out.

I have these settings, per the instructions from the website:

```
LOGDB_MEDIA_ROOT = '/admin/djangologdb/media/'
LOGDB_MEDIA_URL = '/media/djanglogdb/'
```

and I have this in my apache httpd.conf:

```
Alias /media/djangologdb/ "C:/python26/lib/site-packages/django_logdb-1.0-py2.6.egg/djangologdb/media/"
```

but I'm getting 404s when my browser tries to get http://www.example.com/media/djanglogdb/js/jquery.flot-0.6.min.js

Clues for the clueless, anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in something that I was not showing.

Following this line:

```
Alias /media/djangologdb/ "C:/python26/lib/site-packages/django_logdb-1.0-py2.6.egg/djangologdb/media/"
```

I had

```
<Location /media/djangologdb >
  SetHandler None
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Location>
```

And that "Location" directory was wrong.  It should have been a "Directory" directive (because I am serving something off the file system), and the directory has to specify the full directory path.  Like this:

```
<Directory "C:/python26/lib/site-packages/django_logdb-1.0-py2.6.egg/djangologdb/media/" >
  SetHandler None
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the logdb readme](https://github.com/joeribekker/django-logdb) `LOGDB_MEDIA_ROOT` is the absolute path on the file system to media files, whereas `LOGDB_MEDIA_URL` is the web url. So you might perhaps want

```
LOGDB_MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:/python26/lib/site-packages/django_logdb-1.0-py2.6.egg/djangologdb/media/'
LOGDB_MEDIA_URL = '/media/djanglogdb/'
```

**EDIT**

Comparing to my own django installs (although I don't actually use logdb) I have a `<directory>` directive to apply options to the path referenced by the `Alies`, ie

```
Alias /site_media/ "/path/to/project/static/"
<Directory "/path/to/project/static">
    Order allow,deny
    Options Indexes
    Allow from all
    IndexOptions FancyIndexing
</Directory>
```

Depending on how you have Apache set up that might help. It does seem more likely that this is an issue with your Apache setup than with Django and logdb.

Comment: so is LOGDB_MEDIA_ROOT only used when DEBUG=True and the development webserver is serving static files?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with logdb to tell you off the top of my head, but that sounds plausible. The README at https://github.com/joeribekker/django-logdb suggests using `LOGDB_MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(djangologdb.__path__[0], 'media')` to set the media root so it is machine independent.

Comment: It has just occurred to me another reason Apache might not be working, will edit my answer.